# Is there a command `describe-command', similar to command `describe-function'?

Tags: help, ido

I use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> heavily, but this is all functions in Emacs. I'm often only interested in interactive functions, i.e. commands.

Is there an equivalent for commands? Ideally I'd like ido completion too.

Comment: Next question, why is this not in Emacs?

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin: Proposed, but rejected by Emacs Dev.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) defines command `describe-command`.

And it redefines `describe-function` so that it does `describe-command` if you give it a prefix arg.

The library binds `describe-command` to `C-h c` (`describe-key-briefly` is moved to `C-h C-c`).

The same library defines other help commands, such as `describe-file`, `describe-buffer`, `describe-keymap`, and `describe-option-of-type`. Here is [more info](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus) about the library.

Comment: I really like help-fns+, but it's adding a big space and a generic comment on every function I look at: http://imgur.com/NiDlkjS -- any ideas?

Comment: @WilfredHughes: Should be [OK now](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el). (Should also be mirrored on MELPA within 24 hrs.)

Comment: Drew's link from the comment @ 18:25 is broken. 
 https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el works.

Comment: @Realraptor: Thanks. EmacsWiki URLs changed a few years ago.

Answer (score 9):

[`apropos-command`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/apropos-command) might be sufficiently close.

It doesn’t offer `describe-function`’s tab completion, but it lets you
search only through commands, and it takes you
to their doc page.

Answer (score 8):

if you have smex installed, just call smex. Start to type, when the right one comes up, press C-h f.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find this built-in. It is fairly easy to make a wrapper around `describe-function` that only completes command names when called interactively. In the implementation below, I duplicated the interactive form from `describe-function` and changed the `fboundp` test to `commandp`. As an added bonus, this function offers all function names when called with a prefix argument. Change `if current-prefix-arg` to `if (not current-prefix-arg)` to make describing all functions the default.

```
(defun describe-command (function &optional all-functions)
  "Display the full documentation of FUNCTION (a symbol).
When called interactively with a prefix argument, prompt for all functions,
not just interactive commands, like `describe-function'."
  (interactive (if current-prefix-arg
                   (eval (car (cdr (interactive-form 'describe-function))))
                 (list (let ((fn (function-called-at-point))
                             (enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
                             val)
                         (setq val (completing-read (if (and fn (commandp fn))
                                                        (format "Describe command (default %s): " fn)
                                                      "Describe command: ")
                                                    obarray 'commandp t nil nil
                                                    (and fn (commandp fn)
                                                         (symbol-name fn))))
                         (if (equal val "") fn (intern val)))
                       current-prefix-arg)))
  (describe-function function))
```

I haven't tested this with ido but it should integrate normally.

Comment: Quick test shows that it works with IDO.  Copied to `*scratch*`, evaluated then ran `M-x describe-command`.  Commands showed up in a vertical list thanks to `ido-vertical`.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `(describe-function command)`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using helm and `helm-M-x`, you can press `C-j` on the commands to pop up their documentation.